# ¿Animación de refundicion entre dos imágenes como background en Android?

Tags: java, android

Estoy trabajando en Android y me preguntaba como hacer una refundicion o una transición entre dos imágenes, me explico mejor, quiero que como fondo de pantalla este una imagen cualquiera y que después de un tiempo se cambie a otra imagen pero con un efecto de desvanecimiento entra cada una para que el cambio no sea tan brusco.

Debo decir que ya he probado con transiciones pero por algún motivo al probarlo la aplicación termina crasheando, he visto que se podría hacer con una animación separando cada frame pero también leí que eso terminaría ocupando mucho espacio.

Comment: no tuve tiempo de responder antes pero la respuesta veo que la marcaste como correcta solo usando transicion de imagenes, no requerias un Morph?

Comment: Ese efecto igualmente podría servirme, pero la transición por lo que veo es menos escabrosa y da un efecto similar que de hecho me sirve, aun así muchas gracias por tu atención.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cómo indican en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26062245/1468942) android ya tiene una clase llamada `TransitionDrawable` ([documentación de la clase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html)) que te permite simplificar mucho el cambio de imágenes con una transition:

```
TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable( new Drawable[] {
    getResources().getDrawables(mImages[x]), //Imagen 1
    getResources().getDrawables(mImages[y]) //Imagen 2
});
imageView.setImageDrawable(td);
```

Y utilizar

```
td.startTransition(1000);
 // and
td.reverseTransition(1000);
```

Para realizar la transición cada `X` milisegundos (en este caso cada segundo).

Comment: muchas gracias, la respuesta fue de total ayuda.